# How can I style the small squared space between vertical scrollbars and horizontal scrollbars?

Tags: html, css

Please refer to the images below.

[image][image]

When both a vertical and horizontal scrollbar meet, a squared space is created. This happens not only on the browser window, but also in the inner elements that have an overflow.

In my current project, the color of the space creates an unintentional heavy contrast that attracts the attention of the user. **How can I style it so it could be the same color as my background, or even better, "transparent"?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm kind of late to the party here, but in case anyone else stumble upon this...

That specific piece actually has its own class:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
```

If you set the background-color to transparent, the corner will be empty. A better solution might be to set it to the same background-color as in ::-webkit-scrollbar for a seamless transition between the two scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

If you can try this css  code

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar
    {
        width:0px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
    {
        background-coor:transparent;
    }
```